# Why is my function value being called twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, onclick

I have a function that is being called in another function. It should return values of a json object. The json values change based on the filters I have set up.

Why are both values being called instead of just the last one.

My code:

```
$.getJSON(json, api_result => {

      myFunc('#api_results', api_result);
});

function myFunc(id, json_data) {
  $(id).click(function() {
    console.log(json_data);
  });
}
```

My result:

[image: results]

I have updated my filters to change parameters of my json but on click I get all my changes. Why can't I just get the last values of my filtered json?

Comment: `export_data` is `undefined`. What are you asking? `myFunc` is being called once, in your example.

Comment: @StackSlave, my bad. I fixed it

Comment: I have filters that change the json file's data that is being called. For example if I change the date range the json data changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you get a new set of data (from `$.getJSON`) you are calling `myFunc` and binding another handler to the `click` event on `$(id)`. You need to remove any existing click event handlers before binding a new one:

```
function myFunc(id, json_data) {
  $(id).off('click').on('click', function() {
    console.log(json_data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm